# How do I echo POST data into a javascript descriptor in currency format? Stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, php, post, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe form I am trying to add a display for the purchase amount:

```
data-description="<?php echo $_POST['plan']; ?>"
```

but the above outputs errors in the display 'notice undefined variables', even with isset.

The following code work without errors, except once I try and echo POST data.

```
<form action="pages/scharge.php" method="post">
    <div>

        <input type="radio" name="plan" value="2500"> Beta membership <br>
        <input type="radio" name="plan" value="3500"> VIP membership <br>

    </div>
    <div>

                <label for="plan"> If you would like to pay another amount, enter the amount here:</label>
                <input type="text" name="plan" />
                <label for="invoice_num"> Enter the invoice number here:</label>
                <input type="text" name="invoice_num" />

        </div>
        <div>
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
                data-amount="<?php if(isset($_POST['plan'])); echo $_POST['plan']; ?> " data-description=" ">
        </script>

        </div>
</form>
```

How would I echo the POST data in data-description=" " in currency format (stripe is $18.00 = 1800) so that customers can see the proper amount before clicking purchase?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['plan']));` Actually means "If $_POST['plain'] is set, then do absolutely nothing".

Comment: @briosheje just echo'ing it barfs up an 'invalid integer' exception in the checkout code. By dumb luck, isset fixed that error and allowed it to actually carry that POST data to my scharge.php .

Comment: Is this really the *exact* code you're using? I'm asking because, as briosheje notes, `if(isset($_POST['plan']));` with the semicolon at the end is a no-op, and should not have any effect on anything. Or did you accidentally add the semicolon while copy-pasting the code here?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen  the semicolon is an error, ironically I receive behavior with or without it. I just realized my radio button were broke though.

Comment: There is no way without really fancy tricks to get POST data into data-descriptions  because POST happens last. I had to create a separate form page in front with it's own submit button. From there I used a header forward and set $_SESSION['plan'] = $_POST['plan']. From there the checkout used SESSION with data already present, and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work:

```html
data-description="<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['plan'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['plan']);
?>"
```

Note that there is no `;` after `if (isset($_POST['plan']))`.  If you do put a semicolon there, PHP interprets that semicolon as the (empty) statement that the `if` is supposed to conditionally execute.

If you're feeling confused about the semicolons, another, perhaps safer way of writing that would be:

```html
data-description="<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['plan'])) {
      echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['plan']);
  }
?>"
```

Here, you can include as many statements as you want (separated by semicolons) between the curly braces, and they will all be executed only if `$_POST['plan']` is set.  Make sure there's still *no semicolon* between the `if` condition and the `{`, though!

Also, note the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).  Without it, your code is wide open to [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attacks, by an attacker passing in a parameter like `plan="><script>alert("XSS");//`.

Any time you embed a string (that isn't *meant* to be parsed as HTML code) in your HTML output, [you should *always* escape it with `htmlspecialchars()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130534#130534).  Preferably, do this even if you're *sure* that the string cannot contain any characters that could be parsed as HTML markup; it's just a good habit, and may save your code from breaking if you ever decide to change the string later.

Comment: @IImari Karonen  still no output using the following code  https://bpaste.net/show/a555f275456f

Comment: @mine: What does the HTML output look like? Are you actually getting an empty `data-description` attribute, but a non-empty `data-amount`?

Comment: @IImari Karonen yes, empty   http://i.imgur.com/CpcK1aW.png   vs.  http://i.imgur.com/dMu6Roj.png

Comment: OK, but what does the *HTML* look like, if you use View Source (or Inspect Element) in your browser?